# Remove a procedure that's been hacked for elevated rights

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-rds

So I needed to migrate a database but kept getting FK constraint issues, when there shouldn't have been any. Tried to turn off the FK checking, discovered a lack of SUPER privileges. Created a Procedure to change the privilege:

set Global foreign_key_checks=0;

Saved it then modified the definer for it to the rdsadmin user to grant it the rights. It executed fine and did what it was supposed to do. Now I need to switch it back on:

set Global foreign_key_checks=1;

And remove the procedure. I thought I'd use the same technique; just change the definer back to another user, and drop procedure. This does not work:
'CANNOT MODIFY RDSDMIN OBJECT' in 'field list'

Thought about creating a second procedure to remove the right and switch the param, then drop itself , works in MS SQL but not in Oracle apparently.

I'm kind of at a loss on how to do this, any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand what you did or what you are trying to accomplish.  `set global foreign_key_checks=0` isn't valid syntax in a PL/SQL stored procedure.  `set` isn't a valid command in PL/SQL.   `set` could indicate a SQL*Plus directive but the syntax isn't valid for that either.  I have no idea what "SUPER privileges" are, what you mean when you say you "modified the definer for it" and the error message does not appear to be an Oracle error message.

Comment: @JustinCave note the tag `rds` which I believe means the question relates to https://aws.amazon.com/rds/oracle/

Comment: Removed [oracle] tag as this question does not refer to the Oracle RDBMS.

Comment: @DaveCosta - The `rds` tag says to use `amazon-rds` for questions related to Amazon RDS.  But I'd expect that if you're using Oracle in the Amazon cloud that you'd still get Oracle error messages and use standard PL/SQL

Comment: Looks like that directive is `MySQL` @Zexks Marquise please confirm and add the appropriate tag

Comment: Yeah it's RDS on Amazon.

Comment: It's RDS on Amazon, but RDS supports MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, and now their own Aurora database solution.  Which database engine are you using?

Comment: @BruceP We're using MySql

Comment: Now, in 2020, I have the same issue with MySQL on Amazon RDS.  I had to create procedure with definer set to `rdsadmin@localhost` but I didn't manage to do that explicitly so I updated it with query `UPDATE mysql.proc SET DEFINER = 'rdsadmin@localhost' WHERE db = 'mysql' AND name = 'myproc';` and it worked. But, unfortunately, I cannot drop the proc now because of the same error. Have you resolved the issue eventually?

Comment: @pensnarik Nope. The only way I think you can do it is by opening a ticket with AWS and explaining it. I tried that also and got no response, but about a month or so later the proc disappeared with no explanation. I assume someone there saw it and fixed it, but they never said anything.